# ActionScripting Issue: adding/removing children

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, event-handling, removechild, addchild

I have three movie clips all linked to the stage and I want them to behave like a button/ But I am not using a button because I have not found a way to have each part (up, over, down, hit) be animated and not just change when the mouse is in use with it. So far I have been able to have all three appear on my stage and show when I have the mouse over and as well when I click, but I think I'm doing something wrong with removeChild. Each MC should appear one at a time and now all three show up when I hover over and seem to "flash". Here's my code:

```
var mainMoon:swayingMoon = new swayingMoon();
mainMoon.x = 50;
mainMoon.y = 10;
addChild(mainMoon);

var hoverMoon:glowMoon = new glowMoon();
hoverMoon.x = 50;
hoverMoon.y = 10;

var movieMoon:clickedMoon = new clickedMoon();
movieMoon.x = 50;
movieMoon.y = 10;

mainMoon.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, showHoverMoon);
mainMoon.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, hideHoverMoon);
hoverMoon.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startMovieMoon)
function showHoverMoon(event:MouseEvent):void
{
 addChild(hoverMoon);

}
function hideHoverMoon(event:MouseEvent):void
{
removeChild(hoverMoon)
}
function startMovieMoon(event:MouseEvent):void
{
addChild(movieMoon);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend doing it this way as it can make things needlessly complex. For a single button now, you have 3 times as many movie clips/sprites, add/remove child event handlers, and other variables to check/debug for. Multiply this by however many buttons you have.

Instead, I'd recommend using or extending the SimpleButton{} class or writing your own class to encapsulate the behaviour.

SimpleButton class: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/SimpleButton.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you should encapsulate your three moon states into a separate MovieClip that will control all the moon phase changing by itself. If it's already so, fine. The general principle with such a MovieClip-Button type objects is that the listener is assigned to the parent instance, not the parts of that button.

```
public class Moon extends Sprite {
    private var upState:swayingMoon=new swayingMoon();
    private var overState:glowMoon=new glowMoon();
    private var downState:clickedMoon=new clickedMoon();
    private var areWeClicked:Boolean;
    private var areWeOver:Boolean;
    public function Moon() {
        areWeClicked=false;
        areWeOver=false;
        addChild(upState);
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, showHoverMoon);
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, hideHoverMoon);
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, showClickedMoon);
        addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, hideClickedMoon);
    }
    private function showHoverMoon(e:MouseEvent):void {
        areWeOver=true;
        if (areWeClicked) return;
        removeChild(upState);
        addChild(overState);
    }
    private function hideHoverMoon(e:MouseEvent):void {
        areWeOver=false;
        if (areWeClicked) return;
        removeChild(overState);
        addChild(upState);
    }
    private function showClickedMoon(e:MouseEvent):void {
        if (areWeClicked) {
            downState.gotoAndPlay(1);
            return;
        }
        if (overState.parent) removeChild(overState); else removeChild(upState);
        addChild(downState);
        downState.gotoAndPlay(1); // your clicked moon seems to be a playing MC, so starting it over
        areWeClicked=true;
    }
    private function hideClickedMoon(e:Event):void {
        if (e.target!=downState) return; // not our event
        if (!areWeClicked) return;
        areWeClicked=false;
        removeChild(downState);
        if (areWeOver) addChild(overState); else addChild(upState);
    }
}
```

Now, your parent class is controlling what happens and when. I was under assumption that your `clickedMoon` MC will only play once fully, then dispatch an event `Event.COMPLETE` to itself, so that its parent will get notified and will act.

Originally, your event listener structure prevented you from hiding `mainMoon` MC, otherwise your other listener will never act, now you are using parent object to listen to events, and can safely remove parts of your moon.

Answer (score 0):

```
Just for a custom button you are going too much complex way. one movieClip is enough for create the button. First create a movieClip and inside that movieClip's timeline create two more frame for 'hover' and click effect. here is little bit of code to start.


var myButton_btn:CustomButton = new CustomButton();
addChild(myButton_btn);
myButton_btn.x = 100;
myButton_btn.y = 100;

myButton_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, onOver);
myButton_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, onOut);
myButton_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);

function onOver(event:MouseEvent):void {
    //trace('over');
    event.target.gotoAndStop('hover');
}

function onOut(event:MouseEvent):void {
    //trace('normal');
    event.target.gotoAndStop('normal');
}

function onClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
    //trace('click');
    event.target.gotoAndStop('click');

}
```